# Trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables with the following column names.

**users**

ui | email | pass

**user_profiles**

_email | qty | lvl

I am attempting to make sure that everytime a new user is added to the **users** table that the **user_profiles** table creates a new row for the new user. However it fails. After reading through many sample trigger statements I can't seem to find the error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatUserProfilesTBL AFTER INSERT ON users
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_profiles (_email)
VALUES (new.email)
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `FOR EACH ROW`. Additionally, you will need to alter the `DELIMITER` if executing this through the MySQL command line and add a `;` after the insert statement.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updatUserProfilesTBL AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO user_profiles (_email)
     VALUES (new.email);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

According [to the `CREATE TRIGGER` spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html), it is not optional.

Comment: To do this I need to grant myself super permissions. What is the best practice for doing that? Should I add then immediately revoke that privilege?

Comment: @KDEx Use an account that is for administrative purposes only, rather than one used by a functional application.

Comment: As far as I know I am logged as the admin. There is only one account for my db. I've tried running the query from phpMyAdmin as well as SequelPro

Comment: @KDEx Then give yourself the privs you need and immediately revoke them.

Comment: Thanks the permission issue is because I have a small instance on a shared server with GoDaddy...will be dropping them soon. Thanks for the help with the statement!